# Pointer to the same class but with different template type

Tags: c++

I have the same class with different template type instantiation.
Is it possible to point from one to another?

For example, compiling the following code

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
public:
    Base *p;
};


int main() {
    Base<int> a1;
    Base<float> a2;
    a1.p = &a2;

    return 0;
}
```

returns with

```
error: cannot convert ‘A<float>*’ to ‘Base<int>*’ in assignment
   a1.p = &a2;
```

Thanks!

Comment: The compiler is correct, that is not allowable.

Comment: `Base *p;` is actually `Base<T> *p;` see [injected-class-name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name)

Comment: Make `Base` inherit from a non-template class, then store the pointer to that class.

Comment: You could have the template derive from a base class to have an is-a relationship to take advantage of, but that's often harder to get working than it's worth. Very often the functions you want virtualized have templated parameters and you're right back where you started.

Comment: If the template type is different it is no longer the same class. The compiler will create entirely different classes for each template parameter when it instantiates the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have the same class with different template type instantiation.

Actually no, because a template is no class, but describes a *family* of classes. For more detailed information see [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates)

`Base<int>` and `Base<float>` are two different classes, even if they come from the same template, so the compiler is right in your example. You can't have a pointer that can point to both (except for `void*` which is not recommended).

---

Anothe possible solution as proposed by IInspectable would be [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) of that can point to one or the the other like:

```
std::variant<Base<int> *, Base<float> *> ptr;
```

(or preferable with smart pointers instead of raw pointers)

Comment: While you cannot have a (non-void) pointer type, that can point at different template instantiations, you can have a [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) of different pointer types.